# Which type of database should I use for my first Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project that acquires and displays information on how undervalued stock mutual funds and ETFs are (by price/book ratio, price/cash flow ratio, etc.).  My source code is at https://github.com/jhsu802701/bargainstockfunds-scrape .

At the moment, my focus is mainly on the Ruby side.  I am new to the world of Ruby on Rails development, and I'm heeding the advice to learn Ruby first.

I need to use a database to store data acquired by my Ruby script.  I know that there are several options (MySQL, NoSQL, PostGres, etc.), but I have no prior experience with databases.  What do you recommend using and why?  (Best support?  Best performance?  Easier to work with?  Other reasons?)

Comment: I am always working with PostGreSQL, which can be managed by PgAdmin III (available for Ubuntu, very nice). I would recommend you PostGres or MySQL for the beginning. MongoDB, NoSQL are different systems and need more knowledge.

Comment: This question will probably be closed, because it non-constructive. The easiest thing would be to start with SQLite in development. If you use ActiveRecord and migrations you can easily change to a different database later on or in production.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is very convenient during development in Rails. It is small, file-based, and portable.
As a bit of a "perfectionist" I tend to spend a whole lot of time in development, on my local machine.

I, too, have far more experience with MySQL and use it for my production database on Rails projects. Remember that you can configure a different db for each Rails environment ("development", "production", "test").
Rails migrations make it really easy to build up a new database once you switch from development to production.